# How can I iterate through array of deeply nested objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

How can I iterate through an array of deeply nested objects in JavaScript? I would like to iterate through results array of objects.
Something like this:

```
{
      "meta": {
        "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions 
         regarding medical care. While we make every effort to 
     ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are 
     unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to 
     the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
     "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
     "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
     "last_updated": "2019-12-14",
     "results": {
          "skip": 0,
          "limit": 1,
          "total": 504
        }
     },
       **"results": [**
       {
         "effective_time": "20190502",
          "inactive_ingredient": [
           "Inactive ingredients D&C yellow #10, FD&C yellow #6
        ]
```

Comment: Where's your *own* research/effort?  What are you trying to achieve by iterating? In other words, what result do you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering this is your object, you could easily employ `forEach()` or `map()` to iterate through objects inside the `results` array, depending on your need.

Here's a screenshot as an example:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt4Oi.png)

I hope it helped you!

Comment: Adding some results of your code will be much helpful.

Comment: This is how I iterated through: {drugs.map(drug => (
         <div key={drug.id}>
           <li><h5>Effective Date</h5> {drug.effective_time}</li>
           <li><h5>Generic Name</h5> {drug.openfda.generic_name}</li>
           <li><h5>Brand Name</h5> {drug.openfda.brand_name}</li>))}